# protocol Enumerable not implemented for "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, elixir, ecto

I'm trying to send an object and an array of objects from the front end to the back end to save to the database. It has been working in the past but has stopped working, as I've changed the code in the front end, maybe the data I'm posting has become erroneous. Here is an example of my `categories` array of objects in javascript.

```
[{categoryId: 1, label: "Meat", selectedAdd:true, selectedSearch: true, value : 1}]
```

Here is the form data of the request:

[image]

Form data of network request:

```
brand:B.B.
name:be
description:very drab ears 
categories:[object Object]
number_of_votes:0
not_vegan_count:0
rating:0
price:344
shop:[object Object]
```

Here is how I try to get the `categories` array of objects in Elixir and save them:

```
def insert_product_categories(conn, product, product_id) do
      IO.inspect(product, label: "product")
      IO.inspect(product["categories"], label: "product[categories]")
    multi = Enum.reduce(Enum.with_index(product["categories"]), Ecto.Multi.new, fn {product_category, index}, multi -> 
      changeset = Api.ProductCategory.changeset(%Api.ProductCategory{c_id: product_category["value"], p_id: product_id})
      Ecto.Multi.insert(multi, index, changeset)
    end)

    case transaction(multi) do
      {:ok, categories} ->
        # categories here is a map with the index as key and struct as value
          {:ok, categories}
      {:error, failed_operation, failed_value, changes_so_far} ->
        {:error, failed_operation, failed_value, changes_so_far}

    end
  end
```

Here is what my two `IO.inspect`s show:

```
product: %{"brand" => "B.B.", "categories" => "[object Object]",
  "description" => "very drab ears ", "name" => "be", "not_vegan_count" => "0",
  "number_of_votes" => "0", "price" => "344", "rating" => "0",
  "shop" => "[object Object]"}
product[categories]: "[object Object]"
```

Here is the `Api.ProductCategory.changeset`:

```
  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:c_id, :p_id]}
  schema "product_categories" do
    field :c_id, :integer
    field :p_id, :integer
  end

  def changeset(product_category, params \\ %{}) do
    product_category
    |> cast(params, [:c_id, :p_id])
    |> validate_required([:c_id, :p_id])
    |> unique_constraint(:c_id, name: :unique_product_category)
  end
```

My error:

```
17:44:42.497 [error] #PID<0.625.0> running Api.Router terminated Server: 192.168.20.8:4000 (http) Request: POST /products
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for "[object Object]". This protocol isimplemented for: DBConnection.PrepareStream, DBConnection.Stream, Date.Range, Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Stream, File.Stream, Function, GenEvent.Stream, HashDict, HashSet, IO.Stream, List, Map, MapSet, Postgrex.Stream, Range, Stream
        (elixir) /private/tmp/elixir-20170929-57368-1sn104i/elixir-1.5.2/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex:1: Enumerable.impl_for!/1
        (elixir) /private/tmp/elixir-20170929-57368-1sn104i/elixir-1.5.2/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex:116: Enumerable.reduce/3
        (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1847: Enum.map_reduce/3
        (elixir) lib/enum.ex:2697: Enum.with_index/2
        (api) lib/api/models/product_category.ex:31: Api.ProductCategory.insert_product_categories/3
        (api) lib/api/controllers/product/post_product.ex:30: Api.Controllers.PostProduct.post_product/1
        (api) lib/api/router.ex:1: Api.Router.plug_builder_call/2
        (api) lib/plug/debugger.ex:123: Api.Router.call/2
```

How do I get rid of this error? Can I modify my array of objects to be the correct format that the Elixir code is expecting?

Here is my post:

[image]

Comment: Can you not send it as a string with JSON.stringify and parse it on the backend with JSON.parse?

Comment: Pretty sure this is not an elixir/ecto question. The issue is in the javascript.

Comment: @MikeBuhot This is an Elixir question. I need to find out what format Elixir is expecting the javascript code to be, based on the above code. I can't change the javascript until I know that.

Comment: @AbidHasan Because there is a lot of Elixir code already dealing with the payload as it is now.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins: The problem is `"categories" => "[object Object]",` is what is being sent from the javascript side. You need to either send the whole payload as `application/json` or keep it as form encoded and `JSON.stringify` the specific field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments on your question, this isn't an issue in the Elixir backend; the problem is that your JS has serialized the `categories` (and `shop`) value as the string `"[object Object]"`.

`JSON.stringify` is the method you want on the client side, e.g.:

```
.post('http://192.168.20.8:4000/products', JSON.stringify(action.payload), ...
```

The docs for that method are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), and if you are unfamiliar with JSON, I would recommend one of [these](https://developers.squarespace.com/what-is-json/) [articles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON).

Once you make that change on the client side, you may (can't tell, didn't see code for it) need to adjust your Elixir request handler to parse that JSON into an Elixir object.  The library `Poison` is a common choice within the community, but you have many [options](https://hex.pm/packages?_utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=JSON&sort=recent_downloads).

Comment: Op is sending from-data not JSON. JSON.stringify works when you are sending data as json.

Comment: @AtulSharma I think you’re right. This answer will change the code a lot more than i thought was necessary. Which will ripple throughout the app. I will look into it however. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't realize that subtlety, sorry; just going off the `content-type` on the line below. Before restructuring too much, something like `{...payload, categories: JSON.stringify(payload.categories)}` might get you off the ground, before a saner refactor.